# MySQL query help. (delete from where)

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

I am trying to remove a few rows in some of my tables according to an ID from another table (items, purchasedBy).

Here's what I am trying to do..

> DELETE from items.sql where 'PurchasedBy' is 84. DELETE from
>   items_people where item_id is (item_id inside items.sql from the top
>   query) DELETE from items_places where item_id is (item_id inside
>   items.sql from the top query)

so if that makes any sense... here is a sum of what I am trying.. items.sql contains the rows "item_id" and "purchasedBy". items_people and items_places.sql need to have rows deleted according the item_id where the purchasedby is 84..

I really hope this makes sense cause my head is hurting from just thinking of how to explain it... sorry!

Comment: Please can you explain what you are trying to do, maybe by providing a small example? I'm having difficulty making it out :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL supports multi-table DELETE syntax.

```
DELETE i.*, p.*, pl.*
FROM items AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN items_people AS p USING (item_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN items_places AS pl USING (item_id)
WHERE i.PurchasedBy = 84;
```

Comment: Cheers mate. Saved my life.. now I can go to bed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the correct syntax then you can use:

```
DELETE FROM {table} WHERE {param} = 84
```

Replace {table} with your table name and replace {param} with your column where you expect the ID to match ie `item_id` or `purchasedBy`.

I can't give better advice at the moment as I don't really understand your table structure.

Comment: Table structure

items.sql
---------------------
item_id  |  purchasedby
----------------------

items_people.sql
------------------------
item_id

items_places.sql
------------------
item_id

Comment: @Jayden - BillKarwins answer will suit your needs.